# Define paragraph spacing in word included html

Tags: html, css, ms-word, paragraph

I use includetext-function to include html* into a ms word 2010 document:

```
{ INCLUDETEXT  "test.html" }
```

That's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
      body {         
         line-height: 100%;                  
         }     
      p {         
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
         }

   </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Line 1<br/>Line 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't manage to fomat paragraph spacing in word within the html/css. Neither the margin nor the padding property works. All other css properties I checked (font*, white-space, *color*) are working fine.

Without `<p>`-tag word sets paragraph spacing to 10 pt, within `<p>`-tag, I get "auto", which also makes trouble in my complete document.

Which css property is word-compatible to define paragraph spacing?

Thanks a lot.

(* xml with xslt stylesheet - but for demontration simplified)

Answer (score 0):

Use id or class in every p tag(I know it's boring but try it) . I think that'll might work. And also try article or blockquote tag

Answer (score 0):

The margin-property gets only accepted, if I add the property within the style-attribute. Inside the css-class, word ignores it.

This line works fine:

```
<p style="margin:0">Line 1<br/>Line 2</p>
```

strange behavior :-(